# How to transpose multiple columns to multiple rows excel?

Tags: excel

```
Current data set: 
14  72  73
54  75  66
98  87  65
```

Desired outcome: 
    14  72  73  54  75  66  98  87  65

I want to transpose multiple columns to multiple rows, any one have =OFFSET formula to make this done..

Comment: That isn't technically a transposition. You have simply appended each row onto the end of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

If `14` is in A2 then in say E2 and copied down something like:

```
=E1&","&A2&","&B2&","&C2
```

will concatenate the values in a single cell (with comma as the delimiter). To split these out, copy ColumnE, Paste Special, Values over the top and then apply Text to Columns to it, with comma as the delimiter.